# Arithmetic operation on primitive class variables

Tags: java, class, variables, scope, primitive

Couldn't find an explicit description of what's happening so thought i'd bring this up to the community.

```
public class Temp {
static int i;
int j;
int sum = i+j;
}


public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){

Temp obj = new Temp();
obj.i = 1;
obj.j = 2;
System.out.println(obj.sum); //returns '0'

}}
```

Is it because both integers i and j were empty during instantiation that the 'sum' variable is empty?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [*§4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Comment: "Empty" or more precisely they were 0.  Java primitives are never "empty," they are initialized to 0 (or false).  References can be `null` which is not really "empty" either, null is a value.

Comment: To restate what markspace said.  There is no such thing as an "empty" variable or field in Java.  Every variable or field has a *definite value*, any time that you can observe it.  That value is the result of either a definite initialization (e.g. `int foo = 42;`) or an implicit *default initialization*.  Remove "empty variable" from your mental model, and your vocabulary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Temp obj = new Temp(); // creates an instance of object type Temp
```

Here, data members, `i`, `j`, and `sum` are initialized to 0

```
obj.i = 1; // assigns value of Temp data member, i to 1
obj.j = 2; // assigns value of Temp data member, j to 2
```

Note that the value of data member `sum` of Temp Object `obj` is still `0`.
To make, `sum = i + j`, you need to initialize it to `i + j` when `i` and `j` are initialized.

Simply write `obj.setSum()` method to set the value of `sum` and `obj.getSum()` after that to retrive the updated value of it.

```
public class Temp {
    static int i;
    int j;
    int sum = i+j;

    public void setSum(){
        sum = i + j;
    }
    public int getSum(){
        return sum;
    }

}


public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Temp obj = new Temp();
    obj.i = 1;
    obj.j = 2;
    obj.setSum();
    System.out.println(obj.sum); //OR obj.getSum()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because both integers i and j were empty during instantiation
>   that the 'sum' variable is empty?

Yes, `i+j` is assigned to 'sum' when the Object is instantiated. By default java assign 0 to `int` values when you don't assign a value.

You need to update the `sum` variable by directly assigning the value to it.

```
obj.i = 1;
obj.j = 2;
obj.sum = obj.i + obj.j.
```

A workaround is to create a getter method in your Temp class instead of the variable `sum`:

```
public class Temp {

    static int i;
    int j;

    public int getSum() {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

Then to print the sum :

```
System.out.println(obj.getSum());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create another class that will be use by the main method

numeric data fields are set to zero

Character fields are set to Unicode `\u0000`

Boolean fields are set to `false`

Fields that are object references are set to `null` or (empty) for example `String data fields`